# Formatting timestamp results in strange output

Tags: momentjs

Input: `1457690400000`

Call: `moment.unix(1457690400000).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')`

Expected output: `11-03-2016 03:00`

Actual output: `15-05-48162 10:00`

I cannot figure out why this is happening. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with the unix() method in momentjs.

Have you tried: `moment(1457690400000).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm ZZ')` which for me outputs `11-03-2016 11:00 +0100` since I'm in CET.

Verified the result with http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found my error(s). The timestamp I am receiving is actually a string, so moment was getting confused and spitting out that wacky formatting. Furthermore, phuc77 is right in that I was using `.unix()` incorrectly.